# Set exit code of a prompt in a bash shell

Tags: bash, shell, sh

I have a command that returns a number from 0 to n, and would like to catch that number and use as the exit code of the command itself. I was able to achieve it by doing this:

```bash
sh -c $'exit $(command)'
```

But it looks a little bit cumbersome for something so simple as using the stdout of a command and set it as the exit code. Do you know if there's a simpler way to do this?

Comment: Why do you need `sh -c`? Just do `exit $(command)`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you want to capture output of a command then you need a command substitution, *i.e.* your `$(command)`.  If you want to deliver a specific exit status then that's either `exit` or, in a function, `return`.

If you want to do that output-to-exit-status conversion without terminating the shell, then using `()` to run it in a subshell is a better option than running it via `sh -c`.  Examples:

```
(exit "$(command)")

or

wrapper() {
  return "$(command)"
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aside from the fact that this makes only sense as long as `n < 128`, I wouldn't use the exit code to pass a numeric result to the caller. Using the exit code for something else as communicating a specific error type is a misuse of the concept and won't make you happy. In any case, if you want to catch the exit code, you can fetch it via the variable `$?` immediately after your command has been executed.

For instance if the command you mentioned in your question, is called `my_command`,

```
my_command
returnvalue=$?
```

runs it and stores its exit code into the variable `returnvalue`.